# Migrating to new VS2017 .csproj format with migrations

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am converting my project files to this new and shiny VS 2017 project format. I start out by replacing the content with this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>library</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then I add Assemblies and Nuget packages slowly and it all compiles. But how do handle all my migrations? I have around 400. Do I need to add all these as an embedded resource?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything.

The migrations are **code files** so they need to be compiled. According to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#default-compilation-includes-in-net-core-projects), all code files are included in the compilation by default.

And of course, If you try to add a migration to the project with the new format, you will see that nothing changes in the csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

Well. There is actually something you need to do, to make commands like `Update-Database` or `DbMigrator` class work. At least that's what I needed to do for my EF6 project.

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention>true</EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and then to make it work you need to upgrade your Entity Framework to version at least 6.3